# Adding to input field a value with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a Javascript code that should update a form input value, but it does not work.
Here is the code:

```
<script>
function up2(mul)
{
var passcode = parseInt(document.getElementById("passcode").value);
var nou = mul;
var resultat = passcode+nou;
document.login.passcode.value = resultat;
}

function formSubmit()
{
document.getElementById("login").submit();
}
</script>
```

And the html:

```
<body OnLoad="document.login.passcode.focus();">
    <h1>FORM</h1>
    <hr>
    <form name="login" method="post" action="login.php">
        <input type="number" name="passcode">
        <input type="submit" value="Entra">
    </form>

    <center>
    <button onclick="up2('1')">1</button>
    <button onclick="up2('2')">2</button>
    <button onclick="up2('3')">3</button><br>

    <button onclick="up2('4')">4</button>
    <button onclick="up2('5')">5</button>
    <button onclick="up2('6')">6</button><br>

    <button onclick="up2('7')">7</button>
    <button onclick="up2('8')">8</button>
    <button onclick="up2('9')">9</button><br>

    <button onclick="up2('0')">0</button>
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="formSubmit()">ENTRA</button>
</center>       
</body>
```

When the Javascript was only `document.login.passcode.value = mul;` it changed the input value with the number pressed (it didn't add the new number to the one that's in the field). Now I want to make a passcode login, and it should add the number pressed to the field.

If there's a way to do it with jQuery it would be ok.

Comment: "does not work" could mean anything. Give us a hint.

Comment: That's just wrong on so many levels. Read up on event handlers, external scripts, and maybe something as simple as the `autofocus ` attribute etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `getElementById()` but haven't ID attributes on your HTML elements

```
<input type="number" name="passcode">
```

should be

```
<input type="number" id="passcode" name="passcode">
```

FYI, you have the same error on your `<form>` tag.

Comment: It works if I add manually a number in the field, then a button adds the new one next to the original one, but it does not work if it's empty. I'll try to fix that!